# LINQ using String Format

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting the error about `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format` but in the past I was able to do this when I have included `.AsEnumerable()` is there something different I need to do because of the `GroupBy` section?

```
select new PresentationLayer.Models.PanelMeeting
    {
    GroupId = pg.GroupId,
    MeetingId = pmd.MeetingId,
    GuidelineName = pmv.GuidelineName,
    PanelDisclosuresAttendanceURL = string.Format("{0}?MeetingId={1}&GroupId=0",PanelDisclosureLink, pmd.MeetingId),
    }).GroupBy(g => new
    {
        g.MeetingId,
        g.GroupId
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.AsEnumerable()).ToList(),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be aware of the difference between an `IEnumerable<...>` and an `IQueryable<...>`.

### IEnumerable

An object that implements `IEnumerable<...>` represents a sequence of similar items. You can ask for the first element of the sequence, and as long as you've got elements you can ask for the next element. IEnumerable objects are supposed to be executed within your own process. IEnumerable objects hold everything to enumerate the sequence.

At its lowest level, this is done using `GetEnumerator()` / `MoveNext()` / `Current`:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = ...
IEnumerator<Customer> enumerator = customers.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    // There is a next Customer
    Customer customer = enumerator.Current;
    ProcessCustomer(customer);
}
```

If you use foreach, then internally GetEnumerator / MoveNext / Current are called.

If you look closely to LINQ, you will see that there are two groups of LINQ methods. Those that return `IEnumerable<TResult>` and those that dont't return `IEnumerable<...>`

LINQ functions from the first group won't enumerate the query. They use deferred execution, or lazy execution. In the comments section of every LINQ method, you'll find this description.

The LINQ functions of the other group will execute the query. If you look at the [reference source of extension class Enumerable](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs), you'll see that they internally use foreach, or at lower level use GetEnumerator / MoveNext / Current

### IQueryable

An object that implements `IQueryable<...>` seems like an `IEnumerable`. However, it represents the **potential to fetch data for an Enumerable sequence**. The data is usually provided by a different process.

For this, the IQueryable holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The Expression represents what must be fetched in some generic format. The Provider knows who will provide the data (usually a database management system) and how to communicate with this DBMS (usually SQL).

When you start enumerating the sequence, deep inside using GetEnumerator, the Expression is sent to the Provider, who will try to translate it into SQL. The data is fetched from the DBMS, and returned as an Enumerable object. The fetched data is accessed by repeatedly calling MoveNext / Current.

Because the database is not contacted until you start enumerating, you'll have to keep the connection to the database open until you've finished enumerating. You've probably made the following mistake once:

```
IQueryable<Customer> customers;
using (var dbContext = new OrderDbContext(...))
{
    customers = dbContext.Customers.Where(customer => customer...);
}
var fetchedCustomers = customers.ToList();
```

### Back to your question

In your query, you use `string.Format(...)`. Your Provider doesn't know how to translate this method into SQL. Your Provider also doesn't know any of your local methods. In fact, there are even several standard LINQ methods that are not supported by LINQ to entities. See [Supported and Unsupported LINQ methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

**How to solve the problem?**

If you need to call unsupported methods, you can use `AsEnumerable` to fetch the data. All LINQ methods after `AsEnumerable` are executed by your own process. Hence you can call any of your own functions.

> Database Management systems are extremely optimized in table handling. One of the slower parts of a database query is the transport of the selected data to your local process. Hence, let the DBMS do all selecting, try to transport as little data as possible.

So let your DBMS do your Where / (Group-)Join / Sum / FirstOrDefault / Any etc. String formatting can be done best by you.

In your String.Format you use PanelDisclosureLink and pmd.MeetingId. It will probably be faster if your process does the formatting. Alas you forgot to give us the beginning or your query.

I'm not sure where your PanelDisclosureLink comes from. Is it a local variable? If that is the case, then PanelDisclosuresAttendanceURL will be the same string for every item in your group. Is this intended?

```
var panelDisclosureLine = ...;

var result = dbContext... // probably some joining with Pgs, Pmds and Pmvs, 
    .Select(... => new
    {
        GroupId = pg.GroupId,
        MeetingId = pmd.MeetingId,
        GuidelineName = pmv.GuidelineName,
    })

    // make groups with same combinations of [MeetingId, GroupId]
    .GroupBy(joinResult => new 
        {
            MeetingId = joinResult.MeetingId,
            GroupId = joinResult.GroupId,
        },
       
        // parameter resultSelector: use the Key, and all JoinResult items that have this key
        // to make one new:
        (key, joinResultItemsWithThisKey) => new
        {
            MeetingId = key.MeetingId,
            GroupId = key.GroupId,

            GuideLineNames = joinResultsItemsWithThisKey
                .Select(joinResultItem => joinResultItem.GuideLineName)
                .ToList(),
        })
```

So by now the DBMS has transformed your join result into objects with
[MeetingId, GroupId] combinations and a list of all GuideLineNames that have belong to
this [MeetingId, GroupId] combination.

Now you can move it to your local process and use String.Format.

```
.AsEnumerable()
.SelectMany (fetchedItem => fetchedItem.GuideLineNames,

    (fetchedItem, guideLineName) => PresentationLayer.Models.PanelMeeting
    {
        GroupId = fetchedItem.GroupId,
        MeetingId = fetchedItem.MeetingId,
        GuidelineName = guidelineName,
        PanelDisclosuresAttendanceURL = string.Format("...",
                                        PanelDisclosureLink,
                                        fetchedItem.MeetingId);
```

Note: in my parameter choice plurals are collections; singulars are elements of these collections.

```
        PanelDisclosuresAttendanceURL = string.Format("{0}?MeetingId={1}&GroupId=0",PanelDisclosureLink, pmd.MeetingId),
}).
    .GroupBy
```

Comment: the .Select(... => new is that the view model?

Comment: It has nothing to do with ViewModel. There are two syntaxes to use LINQ. Method syntax and query syntax. Those from the C# world prefer Method syntax: `Select(sourceItem => ...)`, because it uses standard C# syntaxes, and it has more functionality. You can look up exactly what it does. It gives you the possibility to "invent" LINQ methods. Those from SQL world prefer to use  method syntax. I don't know this syntax very well. It has less possibilities, you can't extend it, and it is not standard c#

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `string.Format` you first have to get the data from the server.
You can just move the `.GroupBy( ... )` and then the `.AsEnumerable()` call to the top, before `select new PresentationLayer.Models.PanelMeeting { ... }`. If you are not selecting too much data that way...